# While browsing Chrome, I am seeing a blank/partial webpage,especially when I visit Google.com or some other site under Google

Tags: google-chrome, windows-11, blank-screen

I have been noticing this consistently on Chrome. I have Windows 11 on my Office Laptop and version of Chrome is 102.0.5005.115.
For example, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXUhn.jpg) is how Chrome looks like on my PC.
I have tried a lot of things, at first I thought it was due to Adblock or uBlock extension (as they have caused issues on some websites I have browsed earlier as well including on other laptops). I have tried allow listing google.com on the adblock extension(but that also did not help and it seems like a counter productive to me since I want to continue blocking ads on Google).

So I did some other digging and I found a solution suggesting some other Chrome extension could be causing the issue due to some bug in its implementation. So at the time, I disabled each Chrome extension I have one by one, and I thought the Pocket extension was causing the issue, so I disabled it. It seemed that solved the issue for me however this has been popping up much more frequently the past week or so.

So today, I deleted all my Chrome extensions (I had a few like Adblock, uBlock, Leechblock ,Dark reader,Dashlane, a tab theme etc) and reset my browser following the instructions [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/65198869/i-clicked-on-google-chrome-and-its-is-showing-me-a-white-page-with-the-wait-sign-it-wont-load?hl=en).
However, this has very clearly not helped as the first thing I did was a Google search and the same issue happened.

Another bizzarre point to note, is that, I have noticed there are no error logs in the [browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wowI8.jpg). And as you can see, all my Chrome extensions are gone but even then this is happening.

I want to add that the frequency of this occuring is about 50/50. I have noticed this happening on other sites, but most consistently on google.com when I try to query something (and other sites under Google like calendar.google.com, Gmail etc).

Here's another example, from just [now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xXdN.jpg).

I also don't think my office laptop is blocking anything, since I can browse the same site perfectly fine in Guest Mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this has to do with the fact that Google likes to use its implementation of the QUIC protocol when visiting Google sites in Chrome, which uses UDP and can be prone to interference from your networking setup. Can you try looking at the Network tab of the DevTools, and also try capturing the network traffic through [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's an office laptop. Everything I install needs to be vetted by my manager. My work hasn't involved reading packet level data. But I have a 5G network, and on my personal laptop which also has Chrome, it works fine.

Comment: My best guess then is that there is a firewall issue on your office laptop (possibly installed by your company policy) blocking QUIC. To test this, you can try following [these steps](https://help.clouduss.com/ws-knowledge-base/disable-quic-in-chrome-browser) to disable QUIC in Chrome.

Comment: The quic protocol was on its default setting, so I just disabled. Let's see if it works.